# Mostrar hora en QStatusBar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de mostrar la hora en un statusbar en pyqt. Este es mi código:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication, QDesktopWidget,QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import time


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("23.ui",self)


        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.bmax.clicked.connect(self.W_Size)
        self.bmin.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.bclose.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.statusbar.showMessage(self.hora) # error
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("position:right;") # No cambia la posision del texto


    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

    def W_Size(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            qRect = self.frameGeometry()
            centerPoint  = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
            qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
            self.move(qRect.topLeft())
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
    def hora(self):
        self.time = ''
        while True:
            self.time2 = self.time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
            if self.time2 != self.time1:
                self.time1 = self.time2
                print(self.time1)




app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

pero me lanza el siguiente error:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: CRC error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\23\1.py", line 53, in <module>
    p = Principal()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\23\1.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.statusbar.showMessage(self.hora)
TypeError: showMessage(self, str, msecs: int = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'method'
[Finished in 2.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\23\1.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\23]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que `self.hora` es un método de instancia cuando `QStatusBar.showMessage` espera una cadena (o `QString`) como primer argumento tal y como muestra la firma del método:

```
showMessage(self, str, msecs: int = 0)
```

De cualquier forma, usar un ciclo infinito como haces en el método `hora` en una GUI es muy mala idea (cualquier llamada bloqueante en realidad), con ello está bloqueando el *event loop* de la aplicación lo que causará que la interfaz se congele al no poder responder a eventos.

En su lugar puedes usar `QTimer` para llamar al método cada `x` milisegundos para que actualice la hora. Puedes usar una etiqueta para mostrar la hora en el extremo derecho de la barra en vez de usar el mensage. Un ejemplo simplificado:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())

        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.label_hora = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.statusBar.addPermanentWidget(self.label_hora, 0)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        self.label_hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
                                                .toString("hh:mm:ss AP")
                                   )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]